# Best practice to create Generic Validator for Entities

Tags: java, validation, generics

I have a validator that validates Entities having `javax.validation.constraints` annotations:

```
public class EntityValidator {
  void validate(Object obj) {
    ...
  }
}
```

My goal is to make EntityValidator Generic but accept only Entity classes:

```
public class EntityValidator<E extends ???> {
 void validate(E entity) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The entities are having @Entity annotation and are all in the same package, but none of them have a common parent class.

> What is the best practice to connect Entity classes fit to a same type?

The choices I think of:

- Entities implement marker interface (eg. Serializable)
- Create parent class (eg. BaseEntity) and inherit Entities from it.
- Accept classes only with `@Entity` annotation in validator - not sure it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the constraint to be enforced statically, the third option (by annotation) is out.

I'd venture that your best bet would be your own custom marker interface - so that your validation wouldn't interact with other facilities (as it would if you used `Serializable`,) and so that your hands would be left untied with the inheritance hierarchy.